# Добавление подчеркивания к внешним ссылкам

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы было пунктирное подчеркивание только у внешних ссылок?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Смотреть живой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/rh7cz/2/)

```
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #900;
    font-size: 3em;
}
a[href^=http]{
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #900;     
}
a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
</style>
<a href="page.php">Внутренняя</a><br />
<a href="http://site.ru">Внешняя ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Thx!//////